# Why my TabLayout with TabItems not rendering in desing tab

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

I have simply layout with only ConstraintLayout and TabLayout with three TabItems, but for some reasons it's not rendered in design tab. Also I have data layer for binding, but I think it shouldn't be a hindrance. Clarification: when I remove all TabItems, my layout rendering correctly
I also tried to rebuild project, change Constrain to Linear and Frame layout, but it didn't help.

*Edit:* Adding even one TabItem breaks the display

*Edit2:* On device all looks good

**xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Monday" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tuesday" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Wednesday" />


        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine, I just pasted your code in my layout, it works fine. Check your material library version. May be that can be the error.

I am using    `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0-alpha01'`
[image: your code gives this output]

Comment: Oh, yes, my version was outdated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem , when I change my dependencies to :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0-alpha01'
```

render my XML working well.